# Power BI diff time between stages

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a poblem with proper calculate time between stages. I give you a sample of data.
I have in this case three different orders (first column). I want to calculate proper time between stages (index1). For example index1 = 5 substract index1 = 4 but for the same order. Supporting column indicate the same order. How to solve this?

I wanted use smth with filter "EARLIER"
FILTER(Orders,Orders[Supporting Column]=EARLIER(Orders[Supporting Column])

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQgKRB5pcG97Wx6PP_bIBzwGmbv2mZ4YWuFClQG40sU/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try - note, you would do this in Power Query so that the values are there for you in the data model.

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Two new columns have been added to the end.  The first column is the date value from the previous row, when the Student ID for the previous row matches that of the current row.  Now that the values to be computed are on the same row, a second column is added with the difference in time, if there is a value for the previous date.

This solution utilizes a custom function created by Imke Feldmann.

M code for Power Query Table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("fcxNCoAgEIbhq4hrQR2VxF3+tQrai/e/RoqFidVmGPhenpQwxwSv1pVbP01BUWDAkTaMoWPHmTwbaM3SGs6MUHdUJ+t8h8QM9eaC5AskyuR8+IV6A0MzQLJMPsQOwQypsoS4fTf5BA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Student ID" = _t, #"Student Name" = _t, Stage = _t, Date = _t]),
    SourceTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Student ID", Int64.Type}, {"Student Name", type text},  {"Stage", type text}}),
    NextRowDate = fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow(SourceTypes, -1, {"Date"}, {"Student ID"}, ".prev", null),
    DateTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(NextRowDate,{{"Date.prev", type datetime}}),
    AddDuration = Table.AddColumn(DateTimeType, "Time Between Stages", each if [Date.prev] = null then null else [Date.prev] - [Date], type duration)
in
    AddDuration
```

M Code for Custom Function: fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow

```
let
  Source = let
    fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow = (Table as table, optional Step as number, optional SelectedColumns, optional GroupByColumns, optional Suffix as text, optional Buffer as any) =>
    // Source: https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/07/12/fast-and-easy-way-to-reference-previous-or-next-rows-in-power-query-or-power-bi/
    // The only mandatory parameter is your table and then it will return a table with the previous rows values of all columns. So fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow(MyTable) will return the result from above.
    // The default-value for this parameter is set to -1 to return the previous row if you omit it. If you want the values from the next row instead, fill in 1. 2 will return the overnext and -2 the pre-previous row.
    // You probably just need one or a few columns/fields from the previous row: In the 3rd parameter you can enter a list of column names to be returned:   fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow(MyTable, null, {"Value"})
    // Quite often the previous values shall only be returned within a group of rows. (That’s when you use [MyColumn] = EARLIER([MyColumn]) in DAX). You can enter a list of group-columns in the 4th parameter of this function: fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow(MyTable, null, null, {"Product"})
    // By default, the suffix “.Prev” will be added to the new column names. Use the 5th parameter to change if needed. In this example, I reference the row below using “1” for the 2nd parameter: fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow(MyTable, 1, null, null, "Next")
    // If performance is still too bad, you can try to buffer the input table. Any value in the 6th parameter will do that for you (although I haven’t seen a performance improvement for my test cases).
    let
    // Steps to prepare the (optional) parameters for the nested function "fnFetchNextRow"
    Source = if Buffer = null then Table else Table.Buffer(Table),
    Step0 = if Step = null then -1 else Step,
    Step_ = if Step = null then 1 else Number.Abs(Step),
    Suffix = if Suffix = null then ".Prev" else Suffix,
    GroupByColumns = if GroupByColumns = null then null else GroupByColumns,
    ShiftFunction = if Step0 < 0 then Table.RemoveLastN else Table.RemoveFirstN,
    ColNames = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
    NewColNames = if SelectedColumns = null then ColNames else SelectedColumns,
    CountNewCols = List.Count(NewColNames),
    // Core function that retrieves values from previous or next rows (depending on sign of parameter "Step")
    fnFetchNextRow = (Table_ as table, optional Step as number, optional SelectedColumns, optional Suffix as text, optional Buffer as any) =>
    let
    MergeTable = if SelectedColumns = null then Table_ else Table.SelectColumns(Table_, SelectedColumns),
    Shift = if Step0 > 0 then ShiftFunction(MergeTable, Step_) & #table(NewColNames, List.Repeat({List.Repeat({null}, CountNewCols)}, Step_))
    else #table(NewColNames, List.Repeat({List.Repeat({null}, CountNewCols)}, Step_)) & ShiftFunction(MergeTable, Step_),
    Reassemble = Table.ToColumns(Table_) & Table.ToColumns(Shift),
    Custom1 = Table.FromColumns( Reassemble,  Table.ColumnNames(Source) & List.Transform(NewColNames, each _&Suffix ) )
in
    Custom1,
    // optional grouping on certain columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, GroupByColumns, {{"All", each _}}, GroupKind.Local),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each fnFetchNextRow([All], Step0, SelectedColumns, Suffix, Buffer)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.Combine(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom", GroupByColumns & {"All"})[Custom]),
    // case no grouping
    NoGroup = fnFetchNextRow(Source, Step0, SelectedColumns, Suffix, Buffer),
    // select case grouping
    Result = if GroupByColumns = null then NoGroup else #"Removed Columns"
in
    Result,
    documentation = [
    Documentation.Name =  " Table.ReferenceDifferentRow ",
    Documentation.Description = " Adds columns to a <code>Table</code> with values from previous or next rows (according to the <code>Step</code>-index in the 2nd parameter) ",
    Documentation.LongDescription = " Adds columns to a <code>Table</code> with values from previous or next rows (according to the <code>Step</code>-index in the 2nd parameter) ",
    Documentation.Category = " Table ",
    Documentation.Source = "  ",
    Documentation.Version = " 1.0 ",
    Documentation.Author = " Imke Feldmann (www.TheBIccountant.com ) ",
    Documentation.Examples = {[Description =  "  ",
    Code = " fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow( #table( {""Product"", ""Value""}, List.Zip( { {""A"" ,""A"" ,""B"" ,""B"" ,""B""}, {""1"" ,""2"" ,""3"" ,""4"" ,""5""} } ) ) ) ",
    Result = " #table( {""Product"", ""Value"", ""Product.Prev"", ""Value.Prev""}, List.Zip( { {""A"" ,""A"" ,""B"" ,""B"" ,""B""}, {""1"" ,""2"" ,""3"" ,""4"" ,""5""}, {null ,""A"" ,""A"" ,""B"" ,""B""}, {null ,""1"" ,""2"" ,""3"" ,""4""} } ) ) "]}]
in
    Value.ReplaceType(fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow, Value.ReplaceMetadata(Value.Type(fnTable_ReferenceDifferentRow), documentation))
in
  Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DAX solution for a calculated column that gives you the number of seconds between stages, with a blank value for the first stage of an order number. The `ALLEXCEPT` function is doing the heavy lifting here to preserve order number. You can further alter this solution with formatting to show days, hours, etc.

```
Time between stages = 
VAR _index = 'Table'[index]
VAR _time = 'Table'[Data]
VAR _previousTime =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Data] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT (
            'Table' ,
            'Table'[Order Number]
        ) ,
        'Table'[index] = _index - 1
    )
RETURN
DATEDIFF (
    _previousTime,
    _time,
    SECOND
    )
```

Storing current indeces with a variable is for me more intuitive than using `EARLIER` but for these types of not-particularly-complex calculations it is straightforward to swap the variable with `EARLIER`:

```
Time between stages = 
VAR _time = 'Table'[Data]
VAR _previousTime =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Data] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT (
            'Table' ,
            'Table'[Order Number]
        ) ,
        'Table'[index] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[index] ) - 1
    )
RETURN
DATEDIFF (
    _previousTime,
    _time,
    SECOND
    )
```